# SA password not working for .\SQLAdmin

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, password

Had some issues with jobs not working.  To verify it was a security issue, changed the SQL Agent to run under DOMAIN\Administrator.  Answered my question about the security issue.

Went to change the agent account back to .\SQLAdmin.  I used the same password as for the local sa account.  Doesn't work.  I thought sa and .\SQLAdmin were linked.

Are they the same account or is .\SQLAdmin a completely separate account on the local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sa and .\SQLAdmin were linked.

No they are not linked.

`sa` - is [sysadmin](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905197%28v=sql.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is a special high privileged SQL login and is disabled by default.

`.\SQLAdmin` - this means that you want to log in to your local machine having database engine installed. `.` means local machine and `\SQLAdmin` is the instance.

Comment: Is the password for SQLAdmin set by the system when SQL Server is installed?  We have no record of what it is.  I can reset it and then reset all the various services' passwords but that seems like a pain in the behind.

Comment: `SQLAdmin` is just the account you might be using to signify - SQL Server Admin user. Its something specific to your environment. You can ask around or just reset it and fix broken things :-)

Comment: Okay.  Thx very much.

Comment: @MarkJackson glad that it helped. Please mark as answer/upvote so it does not flag as unanswered :-)

Comment: Service users get random accounts when they get created, you can just set a new one and specify it in the service manager as well.